# append only log/event database

Tags: database, cassandra

I have a problem like this - I have to write to disk about 10k events per second. Each event is from 40 to 200 bytes long, and have some timestamp. As far as I understand many people use cassandra for such a case. And it works - I can write 10k events in about 1 second on my a few years old laptop.

But I wonder is there anything better for this case. I have read cassandra manual and it's doing many things that i dont need.

First thing is it adds plenty of metadata for each column and row. Then it makes compaction which i shouldn't need. And deleting rows is kind of complicated and time consuming - tombstones. Then u need to make repairs ...

And all I need is: append new rows only, no queries on anything else but the timestamp range. No updates so I dont need compaction. Then i will want to delete all rows older then some timestamp.

I was thinking about writing data to disk on my own - but clustering, replication, quorums etc might be tricky.

So is there any database which could fit my case better then cassandra?

Comment: If you use TTL, then you can have data expire without deletes. if you only use TTL with no deletes anywhere then you can avoid tombstones. you can look at DTCS as mentioned in another comment

Answer (score 1):

you could take a look at kafka which is more a queue then a database. It seems to be possible to query offsets by time (so you could query for timeranges) ([see FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIaccuratelygetoffsetsofmessagesforacertaintimestampusingOffsetRequest?))

If your timerange deletion requirements are more like a TTL kafka might fit in as well. [The kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction%20%22%22kafka%20docs) state:

> The Kafka cluster retains all published messages—whether or not they have been consumed—for a configurable period of time. For example if the log retention is set to two days, then for the two days after a message is published it is available for consumption, after which it will be discarded to free up space. Kafka's performance is effectively constant with respect to data size so retaining lots of data is not a problem.

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look. Right now I'm thinking about just saving the events into hdfs. I'd want to use hadoop anyway.

Comment: Another thing which might be interesting in cassandra is the relativey new DateTieredCompactionStrategy, which could mitigate some of the disadvanteges you discovered in cassandra for your use case [DTCS ind cassandra docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html?scroll=tabProp__moreCompaction)

Answer (score 0):

[Apache BookKeeper](http://bookkeeper.apache.org/) which is optimized for real time data storage is well suited for append-only data.

Answer (score -1):

This type of data is exactly what [ElasticSearch](http://elastic.co) is for. They even have a special "stack" called ELK (Elastic, Logstash, Kibana). You just throw JSON at a cluster of Elastic servers.

If you use Logstash (which isn't necessary), it will push data into an index like: logstash-myapp-2015-05-07. Next day it rolls the date and you get a new index for each day. By doing so Elastic can dump indexes of a certain age.

Querying is simple, you POST more JSON - or you can use a native (java) api.